# How do I force a 32-bit build of Boost with GCC?

Tags: gcc, boost, 32-bit

How do I force a 32-bit build of Boost with GCC? Currently attempting by putting this line in my `user-config.jam`, but it does not work:

```
using gcc : 4.1.2 : g++ : compileflags="-m32" ;
```

Comment: To build it using bjam, I think you'd do this:

bjam address-model=32 architecture=x86

Comment: Is this on a Linux system…? I generally cheat by using `setarch i686 make` or similar. I don't know if that'd work for Boost, particularly, though. (And, in that case, you could just download the 32-bit binary for your OS, so I'm guessing perhaps you're on another system.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using C++ Boost 1.40, use:

```
bjam address-model=32
```

If you are using eariler version, consider upgrading. If you cannot, use

```
bjam address-model=32 architecture=x86
```

I also recommend that you take a look at the [fine manual](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html)

Comment: Oh yeah... that "fine manual" is great. I love all the examples they provide. (Sarcasm)

Comment: Patches are welcome. However, I am not exactly sure that explicitly adding a full command like example for every single property listed 
at the above URL will do much other than bloating the size of docs.

Comment: Note that if you have a 64 bits version of `gcc`, you should take a look at @AndrewMeadows answer.

Comment: Using Boost 1.44 on OS X 10.6.8, I still find it necessary to specify `architecture=x86`.

Comment: Even for Boost 1.49.0 I had to use the architecture=x86 flag to get this to work on Mac OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 22):

This answer helped me toward a solution that worked for me.  I was trying to compile a 32-bits version of `boost_1_43_0` on 64-bits debian and eventually came up with this:

```
./bjam                 \
  cflags=-m32          \
  cxxflags=-m32        \
  address-model=32     \
  threading=multi      \
  architecture=x86     \
  instruction-set=i686 \ 
  stage
```

Comment: In addition, if you want to change the compiler, you can specify your compiler version via the boost directory's 'project-config.jam' or 'user-config.jam' by making sure that `using gcc : : g++-4.4 ; ` is used (specified 4.4 for compiling Boost with Matlab MEX (32-bit) files on 64-bit linux).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, very usefull answer !