# G++ can't compile code using Boost for x86

Tags: c++, boost, g++, linker-errors

I have a problem: I wrote code using Boost (`locks.hpp`). My server is running x64 Ubuntu (Linux). When i compile this code with `-m64`, it builds fine. But when I try to compile for `-m32`, I get these errors:

```
g++ -fPIC -m32 -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so test.cpp -lboost_thread

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libboost_thread.so when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libboost_thread.a when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_thread.so when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_thread.a when searching for -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Whilst I have no experience with G++: is it possible that you have no 32bit version of boost (kinda how I would interpret the "incompatible stuff")...

Comment: are you sure you installed the 32 bits boost libraries?

Comment: @fvu can you give me a command to install 32 bit boost libraries on x64 ubuntu?

Comment: @Robert no sorry, and when I read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/29665/apt-get-32-bit-package-on-amd64-ubuntu-installation it definitely looks a lot harder than it is on the opensuse I use...

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the 32-bit boost package:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev:i386
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this forces replacement of the current 64-bit development env (compiler and many packages) so it is too intrusive.  Is there a way to have both 32-bit and 64-bit side by side?

Comment: @arielf, yes, there is, but I don't know Ubuntu so I don't know how to do it. I'm amazed that the command above _replaces_ anything, rather than just adding a new package.

Comment: In my experience, this is only an issue with boost.  I have many (C language) libraries installed side by side (multi-arch: 32 and 64 bit) with no issues.  Not sure why the boost `*-dev:i386` package creators forced it to conflict with the default (amd64) boost `-dev` packages.  Since I have several packages already built/installed that depend on the 64-bit version of boost, the `replaces` clause in his `:i386` package, forces the removal of 1) the 64-bit boost version and 2) all the packages that depend on it. :(

Comment: @arielf, it's not an issue with the Boost packages on the distros I use, I'd request the Ubuntu (or Debian) package maintainers to sort it out

Answer (score 2):

You need a 32 bit version of the thread library. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357742/how-do-i-force-a-32-bit-build-of-boost-with-gcc) to your question is already on stackoverflow.com. Use the *address-model* option when you build boost from source. Boost provides great [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) for building on Linux.

```
bjam address-model=32
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how can i add these compiled headers and libs to g++ command?

Comment: You could use the boost "bcp" utility: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @Dan If I use BCP on a 64-bit machine and move the generated folder to a 32-bit machine, will it still work?

Comment: @StevenRoose Yes, it will work. BCP copies copies the source files and dependencies for you; you have to add and build the source files in your project.